# Use Oracle constructor function in PL/SQL package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

On oracle ADB (think it's 19C) I have this working SQL function to rename object storage files:

```
declare
      namespace_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'XX';
      bucket_name varchar2(100) := 'XX';
      region VARCHAR2(30) := 'eu-frankfurt-1';
      cred VARCHAR2(30) := 'OCIDI_CRED';
      rename_values dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t;
      result dbms_cloud_oci_obs_object_storage_rename_object_response_t;
    begin
      -- set the object name and rename values
      rename_values := dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t(source_name                 => '1.txt',
                                                                             new_name                    => '2.txt', -- CSV_Manual/1.txt for example to put in folder
                                                                             src_obj_if_match_e_tag      => NULL,
                                                                             new_obj_if_match_e_tag      => NULL,
                                                                             new_obj_if_none_match_e_tag => NULL);
            

      -- Execute the task and get a status code and the task run key
      result := dbms_cloud_oci_obs_object_storage.rename_object(namespace_name        => namespace_name,
                                                bucket_name           => bucket_name,
                                                rename_object_details => rename_values,
                                                opc_client_request_id => NULL,
                                                region                => region,
                                                endpoint              => NULL,
                                                credential_name       => cred);
                
  dbms_output.put_line('status code: ' || result.status_code);
    end;
```

It is using some oracle types that are seeded and it are a constructor function type:
dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t;
dbms_cloud_oci_obs_object_storage_rename_object_response_t;

How do i properly convert this code to run in a plsql package?
having issues on how and where to declare them

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'having an issue'? is it returning an error?

Comment: Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY BI.CLOUD_STORAGE

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CLOUD_OCI_OBJECT_STORAGE_RENAME_OBJECT_DETAILS_T' must be declared
Line: 7
Text: rename_values dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t;

Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line: 1
Text: create or replace package body bi.cloud_storage is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need to wrap the PL/SQL block with package syntax?

```
create or replace package cloud_storage is
      procedure rename_files;
end;
/

create or replace package body cloud_storage is
procedure rename_files is
      namespace_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'XX';
      bucket_name varchar2(100) := 'XX';
      region VARCHAR2(30) := 'eu-frankfurt-1';
      cred VARCHAR2(30) := 'OCIDI_CRED';
      rename_values dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t;
      result dbms_cloud_oci_obs_object_storage_rename_object_response_t;
begin
      -- set the object name and rename values
      rename_values := dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t(source_name                 => '1.txt',
                                                                             new_name                    => '2.txt', -- CSV_Manual/1.txt for example to put in folder
                                                                             src_obj_if_match_e_tag      => NULL,
                                                                             new_obj_if_match_e_tag      => NULL,
                                                                             new_obj_if_none_match_e_tag => NULL);
            

      -- Execute the task and get a status code and the task run key
      result := dbms_cloud_oci_obs_object_storage.rename_object(namespace_name        => namespace_name,
                                                bucket_name           => bucket_name,
                                                rename_object_details => rename_values,
                                                opc_client_request_id => NULL,
                                                region                => region,
                                                endpoint              => NULL,
                                                credential_name       => cred);
                
      dbms_output.put_line('status code: ' || result.status_code);
end;
end;
/
```

Then you can call the package and procedure with:

```
begin
      cloud_storage.rename_files;
end;
/
```

Comment: The issue is exaclty there. when you create a package you get:
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY BI.CLOUD_STORAGE

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CLOUD_OCI_OBJECT_STORAGE_RENAME_OBJECT_DETAILS_T' must be declared
Line: 7
Text: rename_values dbms_cloud_oci_object_storage_rename_object_details_t;

Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line: 1
Text: create or replace package body bi.cloud_storage is

Comment: i was just missing grants. forgot that